# Applying a WIM with duplicated file entries

Tags: windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux, dism, wim, imagex

I wanted to cleanup the partition table on my drive, so I grabbed another drive and made a Windows To Go workspace. In that WTG system, I backed up my exising Windows 10 with DISM. Then I cleaned the disk and re-partitioned before I attempt to apply the WIM image back.

Now however I attempt to *apply or mount* the image, both DISM and ImageX get stuck and quit at file `\Users\iBug\AppData\Local\lxss\rootfs\lib\xtables\libip6t_HL.so`. Both are reporting "Error 5: Access denied." I know it's a file from Windows Subsystem for Linux.

I set up 7-Zip and opened the WIM file and it seems OK. I navigated to that folder and was surprised to see 2 files with the same name there, only differing by cases. That is, I have `libip6t_HL.so` AND `libip6t_hl.so` in the same place. I think that's the problem because NTFS doesn't have its case sensitivity support enabled by default (it does have support, though).

So how can I apply the WIM correctly? I am eager to destroy those files (or even the whole WSL setup if required).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally restored my Windows 10 installation from backup!!!

I used a Chinese utility called WimTool. In its main UI there's a "Edit Configuration" button. I added `\Users\iBug\AppData\Local\lxss` to `[ExclusionList]` section, then applied the WIM. As expected, the folder was ignored and no more errors popped up. After restoring Windows 10 setup, simply [reinstall WSL](https://www.howtogeek.com/261188/).

According to my experience, non-Chinese users should be able to do this without that tool, but ImageX. Microsoft provided [a tutorial on creating ImageX configuration file](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766147(v=ws.10).aspx), and in the tutorial they disclosed the **Default Exclusion List** for ImageX (same for DISM). All you need to do is copy down the default list and add the desired line to it. Then when applying the image, supply `/Config yourfile.ini` to ImageX and it'll ignore your specified directories.

Answer (score 1):

FYI...

This is a known problem with imagex in Windows 10 1607. There's a Microsoft [KB article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3179598/dism-apply-image-command-fails-with-error-code-5-error-access-denied) on it. The article doesn't say if Windows 10 1703 fixes it.

Microsoft's "solution" is to not install WSL before capturing the image. Your solution of excluding the lxss directory is better :-). Still a *Pain In The ASCII* to have to reinstall WSL.

Comment: The problem is, I didn't know the bug before capturing, and all I have is the WIM file after formatting the drive and attempting to restore (and noticed the error).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `wimupdate` in [wimlib](https://wimlib.net/) to remove the WSL, and then you will be able to successfully restore the image.

The specific command is as follows:

```bsh
cat > update_commands.txt << EOF
delete --recursive /Users/{your_username}/AppData/Local/Packages/CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc
EOF

wimupdate {your_backup}.wim 1 < update_commands.txt
```